# Modal Bootstrap is open and closing after being called from a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I  try to call a  bootstrap modal window from a click event.

If I try to call it directly  I do not have problems. 
If I try to call it from a function, then the window opens and closes immediately.

I searched  and saw that the only instance I found  that this behaviour occurs is when  I have the bootstrap js file repeated but as you can see in my fiddle that is not the case.

Even though I can progress in my project calling the modal directly,  I would want to make sure that this is some kind of restraint rather than a situation that would bite me later.

I am using `Bootstrap R. 3.3.4` and `jquery 2.1.4`.

This is my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/calito22/gf9h8ez4/10/

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default yvmc-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="yvmc-header--top-right-link--container text-right hidden-xs">
    <a href="" id="test"  class="top-right--link  showCreatePropertyWizard">CLick here to see the modal</a>     
   </div>
   </div>
   </nav>

   <div class="modal fade active" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Ingresa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body login-modal--body">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <p id="registrate" class="modal-sub-title text-center">&iquest;No est&aacute;s Registrado? <a href="">Reg&iacute;strate aqu&iacute;</a></p>
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span aria-label="email" class="input-group-addon email-login-icon"></span>
                                    <input autofocus size="100" type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailLogin" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon password-login-icon"></span>
                                    <input size="100" type="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordLogin" placeholder="Clave">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value=""> Recordar Sesi&oacute;n
                                </label>
                                <span class="" style="float: right;"><a href="">&iquest;Olvidaste tu clave?</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="submit" id="ingresar" class="btn blue-button">Ingresar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      $("#test").on("click",function () {
         wizardproperties();
     });
     function wizardproperties(){
      $('#loginModal').modal('toggle');
      return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jslight/gf9h8ez4/11/)

```
$("#test").on("click",function () {
   wizardproperties();
});
function wizardproperties(){
  $('#loginModal').modal('show');
  return false
}
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for your response. I tried your response but I had the same error.  Extending the details of my question, if try this:                                                                     $("#test").on("click",function () {  
      $('#loginModal').modal('show');  
      return false;  <br/>
  });                                                                                                       

Works. This what I would do with my project. I just wanted to know if this is the expected behaviour or if this is something I have to take care of.

Comment: if you want to open modal on click event it is perfectly right. if you have complex logic or reusability code which you don't want to write in click event you can create separate function and use that function in click event.

Comment: I am afraid is  not working with your suggested solution :  https://jsfiddle.net/calito22/gf9h8ez4/17/

Comment: You are trying to submit a form through jsfiddle. check "https://jsfiddle.net/jslight/gf9h8ez4/18/"

Comment: Hi Rakesh, tried to enter in your link but is broken.

Comment: Yes, worked in the fiddle and in the project. Thks for your time!. that was the solution:   $("#test").on("click",function (e) {
   wizardproperties();
   e.preventDefault();
});
function wizardproperties(){
  $('#loginModal').modal('show');
  return false
}